# Problem updating Arduino WiFi Shield's Firmware

Tags: wifi, firmware

I'm using Arduino Uno R3 and the official Arduino WiFi Shield R3. I'm trying to update the Shield's firmware to 1.1.0 through [***this***](http://www.bustatech.com/upgrade-arduino-wifi-shield/) guide.

Everything goes fine until Step 9. When I execute the code in Step 10, I get an error (see attachment) as:

`AtLibUsbDfu: 3EB 2FF8 no device present`

`FAIL Could not open USB device.`

`ISP done.`

[image]

***EDIT:*** I re-installed the firmware on my shield and now the problem's gone.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment because of reputation... You've already upgraded the firmware. Just when you try upgrading again your wifi device is rebooting itself because of upgrading before.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the online instructions do not work. This one does - http://arduinotronics.blogspot.com/2015/06/upgrading-arduino-wifi-shield-firmware.html